# c++ code equivalent since c#?

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-c++

How do you code this code in c++?

```
    public bool returnboolean(bool x) 
    { return x; } 
    public double sum(double one, double two) 
    { return one+two; } 
    public string yourname(string name) 
    { return "hello "+yourname; }
```

Where do i go to write code? in *.h? or in *.cpp?

What is their goals of those 2 classes?  Because then I added a class they 2 clases are created.

How do you create an instance?

For example in c#:

```
person p1 = new person();
```

What is the equivalent of this in c++??

Comment: It's still difficult to tell what's being asked here.

Comment: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/CppTutorial/NOTES/CLASSES-INTRO.html

Comment: Gosh @angel - you really need to read a basic primer on C++ first and ask questions about what you don't understand rather than expecting people here to write a basic primer for you.

Comment: When you say "those 2 classes" what are you referring to?  .h and .cpp?  They are files, not classes.

Comment: I don't feel that this site should be your "tutorial". If you have a *very specific* programming question, then please ask it. Asking "please convert the following code for me, because I don't know C++" is a bit much.

Comment: how do i add clases in visual studio? when i do "add class" they are added.. @James

Comment: Like in many 'c' like languages, source code is contained in two different file types, .h and .cpp in the case of C++.  In C it is .h and .c, and in objective-c it is .h and .m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string>

public:
bool returnboolean(bool x)
    {
        return x;
    }
    double sum(double one, double two)
    {
        return one+two;
    }
    std::string yourname(std::string name)
    {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
```

Comment: @Seth: yes you can - see here http://ideone.com/hzq2a#

Comment: Yeah, that's why I deleted my comment. Why does that work though? Seems like you're adding a string to a `char const[7]`.

Comment: @Seth: Because the + operator is overloaded to take both std::string + std::string and char* + std::string.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh I see, because you have to have at least one user defined type in an operator overload but not necessarily two, and the user defined type doesn't have to be on the left. Sweet, thanks very much. +1

Comment: @Seth: See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operator+/ `string operator+ (const char* lhs, const string& rhs);`